# Mean time to absorption for finite general birth death process with one absorbing state

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

I have a continuous birth-death chain $\{X(t)\}$ on state space $\{0, 1, \dots, n-1, n\}$, with birth rates $\lambda_i$ and death rates $\mu_i$, where state 0 is absorbing ($\mu_0 = \lambda_0 = 0$), and the right-most state is not absorbing (could be reflecting, doesn't matter).

What is the mean-time to absorption into state $0$ if I start the process at any state $n \geq j \geq 1$? All the resources I have found seem to apply to infinite processes, or to finite processes with both endpoints being absorbing.

EDIT: Looking for a result still.

Comment: The general theory says $k_i:=\mathbb{E}(T_0| X_0=i)$ satisfies the recurrence
$$k_i = \frac{1}{\gamma_i} +\frac{\lambda_i}{\gamma_i}k_{i+1} +\frac{\mu_i}{\gamma_i}k_{i-1},$$
for $1\leq i \leq n-1$ with $k_0=0$, where $\gamma_i=\lambda_i+\mu_i$. If I recall correctly, one can solve the same problem on the infinite state space $S=\{0,1,2,\dotsc\}$ and then use some form of truncation argument to get the answer for the case $S=\{0,1,\dotsc, n\}$. I unfortunately don't remember the details but I do recollect seeing it on this site somewhere...

Comment: @LoveTooNap29 yep, I suspect it's here somewhere, but I looked extensively to no avail ...

Comment: @LoveTooNap29 can you expand on what you mean by truncation argument here?